# Form for billing information

Tags: forms, billingblock

How to remove the "Second name" field in the billing form, I can not find the path to reach this form and modify it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot control billing block fields through UI. There is no such settings since this fields are mandatory for some(infact many) payment processors. This fields are hard coded at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Core/Payment.php#L869

You can use [buildform](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm/) hook to remove the second name field.

> Note: You might get error from some payment processor if second name
>   is empty

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: I could uncheck the billing and put the fields chosen by me to ask who to send the invoice...

Comment: I saw that I can uncheck, so the pre-filled form with the billing fields does not appear: in Contributions> Manage Contribution Pages> Configure Page> Amounts> billing address required ... "Check this box later option to provide billing name and address "  -  In this way, I can put a form with fields chosen by me, for billing  -  Thanks Pradeep; for your NOTE: You might get error from some payment processor if second name is empty...
I tried with the empty field "second name", I had no problems, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the field with CSS, can't you?

Or comment this out in CRM/Core/BillingBlock.tpl:

```
  if ($('#middle_name').length)
    input_ids['#middle_name'] = '#billing_middle_name';
```